# No such entity after migration tool

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, no-such-entity-exception

I was able to start migration tool between 1.9.0.1 and 2,2 but it did not complete due to mismatch of data.

When i logged in to M2 backend, css was gone and i just had a white background with the links. Frontend was working.

I did reindex and clean the cache but had a 'no such entity" message.
On the exception.log i can see this error:

[image: exception.log]

On the websiteRepository.php I see this block:

public function getById($id)
    {
        if (isset($this->entitiesById[$id])) {
            return $this->entitiesById[$id];
        }

```
    $websiteData = $this->getAppConfig()->get('scopes', "websites/$id", []);
    $website = $this->factory->create([
        'data' => $websiteData
    ]);

    if ($website->getId() === null) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException();
    }
    $this->entities[$website->getCode()] = $website;
    $this->entitiesById[$id] = $website;
    return $website;
}
```

Line 102 is:  throw new NoSuchEntityException();

Now I cannot access frontend or backend,I just have a blank page.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Emilie